# Can I kill everybody who is in the basement of the blue palace? Including Jarls, housecarls and servants without any consequences?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I am annoyed with the people down in the blue palace basement. They call me names, threaten me, and the NPC's down there are just down right mean. So I suggest I give them a taste of their own medicine and kill all of them. Now I heard if you kill Jarls, your save game can break; and I was wondering if there's any way around this without my game breaking. If there is or isn't, or if there's another way, let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this is that some characters may have an `essential` tag in their code, meaning that they just cannot die by normal means. If you're on PC, you can remove this tag, and then you'll be able to kill them.

As for "breaking your game", if a character is essential, and you do kill them (through the use of commands), they will no longer be able to contribute to the story, and the story will no longer be able to continue.

So all in all, there will be consequences.

1. They will survive, and in game, you will be charged with murder for killing everyone else, as they will survive as a witness. You'll have to deal with that in game.
2. You remove the `essential` tag, and kill eveybody. Later in the game, you will be required to visit one of the people you killed, and be unable to continue the story.
3. If they aren't essential, the worst that could happen is that you lose the ability to complete that quest. In which case all you'll get is a notification that you failed a particular quest. The game will be able to continue unhindered otherwise.

Comment: Also yes I am on PC with 46 mods.

Answer (score -2):

## Can I Kill All Of Them?

Well, no, because some normally can't be killed. They just fall to their knees and then go back up.

## Am I Able To Kill Some Of Them?

You can. It just needs a lot of skill to do so. You must have a high Sneaking skill with some perks (to prevent any crime). You might also need very good weapons to destroy them too. Increase your weapon skills, improve them, and/or forge new ones that are stronger.

## What About My Game Breaking?

Don't worry about it. Anything can break your game. Just be careful when you try to do this.